# How to search files in the drive that are created within a week period?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How to search files in the drive that are created within a week? Currently, the search function search files by modified date/time and not created date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search or filter files with the files.list methods of the Drive API. Use the '*orderBy*' parameter and '*createdDate*' as valid key.

Example: orderBy=createdDate

For more information regarding file request, please follow this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: thanks for your answer, i revised my question to be more clear sorry for a confusing question. I meant searching for files with a created date (let say - today or within a week time period)