# Get latest google sheets with its SpreasheetID and SheetID from google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I want to get sheetID from Spreadsheet/file that I searched within drive. I get the spreadsheetID but not the sheetID.

Here's the function:

```
function searchSheets(){
     var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "latest"');
     while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();
     var ss = file.getId();
     var sss_ID = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss).getSheetId();
     Logger.log(sss_ID);
}
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: You should use DriveApp or the Advanced Drive Service. One option is to search  for files by createdTime and mimeType. If you need further help, please show what you have tried to find the latest spreadsheet (all the other stuff in the question could looks to be unnecessary) .

Comment: @Rubén - Thanks though. I modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no efficient way to get the latest spreadsheet by using the DriveApp.searchFiles method (the OP's code search for files having `latest` string in the file title).

One option is to use the Advanced Drive Service:

```
/**
 * Logs the file name, id, creation date and URL of the most recent spreadsheet
 */
function searchSheets() {
  const response = Drive.Files.list({
    /** 
     * Required properties 
     * @property {string} q - Query
     * @property {string} orderBy - Required because list returns paged results
     */
    q: `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'`,
    orderBy: 'createdDate desc',
    /** 
     * Optional properties, 
     * @property {string} fields - Limits the fields to be included in the 
     * response. When omitted, all the File fields will be included 
     */
    fields: "items(id,title,createdDate,alternateLink)"
  })

  const newest = response.items[0];
  console.log(newest.title, newest.id, new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'America/Mexico_City',
    timeZoneName: 'short'
  }).format(new Date(newest.createdDate)), newest.alternateLink);
}
```

Once you get the id of the latest spreadsheet, it might be used to open it using the Spreadsheet Service or the Advanced Google Sheets Service to get the id.

Related

- [How to search files in the drive that are created within a week period?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34975262/1595451)

Comment: How can I get spreasheetID and sheetID?

Comment: To get the spreadsheet id using the code in the answer, use `newest.id`. To get the sheet id you have you use the Spreadsheet Services or the Advanced Spreadsheet Service. If you need further help, please post a new question providing more details about how to identify the sheet that you want to get the sheet id, if that sheet is always the default sheet, if always it's the first sheet, etc.

Comment: I want both SpreadsheetID and sheetID - so it is part of my original question. I get the spreadsheetID but the sheetID is garbage. I have edited my original question with the output file.

Comment: I think that the question doesn't have the details that I asked on my previous comment, anyway, I edited my answer. If you need a different code I suggest you to post a new question providing the required details, or just be patient for another answer.